# C++ 1st Time Working With Functions

Tags: c++, function

As the title states, I'm working with Functions for the first time and I'm having difficulty implementing them into the hangman game. From my limited knowledge, I'm assuming the scope of my variables are out of reach from the function calls. Given that I'm working completely out of a book, I feel that I've hit a wall. I was thinking possibly going with Global Variables but then again, the chapter I'm working on only gave me a limited understanding on them too. I'm also having problems with srand(time(0)); for some reason as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
// HangMan Game
// With Functions

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

char playerGuess();
char guessInWord();

int main()
{
    //setup
    const int MAX_WRONG = 8;//max wrong will be set at 8

    vector<string> words; //collection of possible words to guess
    words.push_back ("DAFTPUNK");
    words.push_back ("ELSALVADOR");
    words.push_back ("HIPHOP");

    srand(time(0));
    random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end());
    const string THE_WORD = words[0];            //word to guess
    int wrong = 0;                               //number of incorrect guesses
    string soFar(THE_WORD.size(), '-');          //word guessed so far
    string used = "";                            //letters already guessed

    cout << "Welcome to Hangmam. Good luck!\n";

    //main loop
    while ((wrong < MAX_WRONG) && (soFar != THE_WORD))
    {
        cout << "\nYou have " << (MAX_WRONG - wrong) << " incorrect guesses left.\n";
        cout << "\nYou've used the following letters:\n" << used << endl;
        cout << "\nSo far, the word is:\n" << soFar << endl;

        char guess = playerGuess(); //call to function 1

        used += guess;

        guessInWord();              //call to function 2
    }

    //shut down
    if(wrong == MAX_WRONG)
        cout << "\nYou've been hanged!";
    else
        cout << "\nYou guessed it!";

    cout << "\nThe Word was " << THE_WORD << endl;

    return 0;
}

//function Definitions 1
char playerGuess()
{
    char letter;
    cout << "\n\nEnter your guess: ";
    cin >> letter;
    letter = toupper(letter); //makes uppercase of letter
    while (used.find(letter) != string::npos)
    {
        cout <<"\nYou've already guessed " << letter << endl;
        cout <<"Enter your guess: ";
        cin >> letter;
        letter = toupper(letter);
    }
    return letter;
}

//function Definitions 2
void guessInWord()
{
    if (THE_WORD.find(guess) != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "That's right! " << guess << " is in the word.\n";

        //update soFar to Include newly guessed letter
        for (int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i)
            if (THE_WORD[i] == guess)
                soFar[i] = guess;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry, " << guess << " isn't in the word.\n";
        ++wrong;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you face?

Comment: where you hit the wall?

Comment: @ThuggedOutNerd: You should post this in Code Review at codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I was just stuck on how to make my functions communicate with one another and with main. I did what MM suggested and made the variables he mentioned into Globals. The program now works up to the point where a letter is guessed right. At the point its guessed correctly the program crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of your functions should not differ from it's implementation:

```
void guessInWord();  ------> char guessInWord();
^^^^                         ^^^^
```

Make these global (I personally don't prefer to make global) because you're using them in the other functions:

```
vector<string> words;
string used;
string THE_WORD;
int wrong;
string soFar;
char guess;
```

Absolutely you will have run-time errors or logical issues., go ahead...

```
char playerGuess();
char guessInWord();

vector<string> words;
string used = "";
string THE_WORD;
int wrong = 0;
string soFar(THE_WORD.size(), '-');
char guess;

int main()
{
    const int MAX_WRONG = 8;

    words.push_back("DAFTPUNK");
    words.push_back("ELSALVADOR");
    words.push_back("HIPHOP");

    THE_WORD = words[0];

    srand(time(0));
    random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end());

    cout << "Welcome to Hangmam. Good luck!\n";

    while ((wrong < MAX_WRONG) && (soFar != THE_WORD))
    {
        cout << "\nYou have " << (MAX_WRONG - wrong) << " incorrect guesses left.\n";
        cout << "\nYou've used the following letters:\n" << used << endl;
        cout << "\nSo far, the word is:\n" << soFar << endl;

        guess = playerGuess();
        used += guess;
        guessInWord();
    }

    if (wrong == MAX_WRONG)
        cout << "\nYou've been hanged!";
    else
        cout << "\nYou guessed it!";

    cout << "\nThe Word was " << THE_WORD << endl;

    return 0;
}

char playerGuess()
{
    char letter;
    cout << "\n\nEnter your guess: ";
    cin >> letter;
    letter = toupper(letter); //makes uppercase of letter
    while (used.find(letter) != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "\nYou've already guessed " << letter << endl;
        cout << "Enter your guess: ";
        cin >> letter;
        letter = toupper(letter);
    }
    return letter;
}

char guessInWord()
{
    if (THE_WORD.find(guess) != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "That's right! " << guess << " is in the word.\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i)
            if (THE_WORD[i] == guess)
                soFar[i] = guess;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry, " << guess << " isn't in the word.\n";
        ++wrong;
    }
}
```

Comment: one being void and the other char was my bad from trying different things to get it to work... I've been trying so many things I just forgot to switch em back. Thanks I'll give it a go.